# "Add new table" option missing - Visual Studio 2015

Tags: sql, visual-studio

I'm working on Visual Studio 2015 and whenever I try to add a table from the server explorer menu, it only shows two options **Properties** and **Refresh**.

There have been answers for [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WEhm.png) problem, but I have already tried them, like, adding SQL data tools and repairing visual studio.

SQL data tools were already installed and even after repairing the problem persists.

So please suggest me how can I add tables to the database.

Comment: Check whether your user have access to tables.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to check that?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188371.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the comments, but i solved the problem.

Open the command prompt and type the command:

```
C:\sqllocaldb create "MyInstance"
```

*MyInstance* refers to your sql server instance, it can be **v11.0** but for me it was **mssqllocaldb**  .

If it runs successfully, it will show you result stating 'Instance created' and you will be able to add the tables.

But if you get error regarding creation of instance then delete the instance by typing the command in command prompt:

```
C:\sqllocaldb delete "MyInstance"
```

and then create the instance.

I hope this helps.

Comment: this is the best solution for such a problem

Comment: Thanks, it worked like a charm! Please navigate to C drive in command prompt and then type - sqllocaldb create "MyInstance" . I initally got confused and tried to go to sqllocaldb folder..

Answer (score 1):

1. Close your visual studio.
2. [Download SQL Server Data Tools](https://download.microsoft.com/download/3/4/6/346DB3B9-B7BB-4997-A582-6D6008796846/Dev12/EN/SSDTSetup.exe)
3. Install it in your pc
4. Then Close if successfully installation.
5. Now Open your visual studio.

Hope this will help.
Enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

Another reason "**Add New table**" Not showing is **you don't have installed SQL server Data Tools**.So just go ahed and downlaods SQL server data tool ISO from official Website

https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=863443&clcid=0x409

Install the SQL Server Data Tool And Restart Visual Studio

Answer (score 0):

**Download** and ***Install*** **SQL server data** from the link given below,
https://download.microsoft.com/download/3/4/6/346DB3B9-B7BB-4997-A582-6D6008796846/Dev12/EN/SSDTSetup.exe

After installing the **SQL** server you will be able to add a new table.
**Table** > **right click**> **Add new Table**.

Comment: So basically you recommend exactly the same as the 19 months older answer by Rj_Innocent_Coder? If not, please elaborate the difference.